# Angular5 with Asp.Net Core 2.1 application deployment problem on nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, asp.net-core, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy Angular 5 application Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.4 Nginx. But Angular application is not working properly from there.

I am able to do below:

http:://ipaddress/api/values
http://domainname/api/values

But website for angular is not working:

http://domainname
http://ipaddress

I tried several combination to access the application but it did not work for me.

You can see the below default file for nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

#       root /var/www/html;
        root /home/xxxx/www;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

#       server_name _;

#       location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #       proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        #}
}
```

With this default file I have done with multiple location but again it didn't work.

Can you please tell me how do I deploy Angular application running along with dotnetcore 2.1 api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow in dotnet app.UseStaticFiles(); was commented. I removed the comments and yeah it started working.